# Java - Compare item of String array with a String

Tags: java, string

I really don't understand what's wrong right now.

```
String s = "a,b,c,d";
String[] test = s.split(",");
System.out.println(test[0]);
System.out.println(test[0] == "a");
```

Console prints:

```
a
false
```

That doesn't make sense at all. test[0] is "a" and ("a" == "a") is false ?

Excuse me for my bad english.
Thanks!

Comment: Use the `equals` method.

Answer (score 0):

`==` tests for reference equality.

`.equals()` tests for value equality.

Look [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java).

Comment: True, but a noob who doesn't know to compare strings with .equals() probably doesn't know what "reference equality" and "value equality" mean.

Comment: I also give a question url to larsklaus in my answer. So larsklaus can have more information about these.

Comment: Oops!  I missed seeing the link.